# Adding Seamonkey/Firefox extensions to custom LiveCD

Tags: live-cd, customization, extension

Is there a way to add Seamonkey extensions to a custom Ubuntu LiveCD?

I'm working with UCK, and I would like to add a language pack extension (.xpi) to Seamonkey so that the language would be available as the default language of the application in the customized CD.

Answer (score 2):

Two options for creating custom ISO for ubuntu:

1. [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html): A tool that can be used to do 2 things with an existing Debian,  Ubuntu or derivative installation.  It can make a full system backup including personal data to a live cd or dvd that you can use anywhere and install.  It can make a distributable copy you can share with friends.  This will not have any of your personal user data in it.  How to use this tool w/ Ubuntu: http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html.
2. [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/): A tool with a graphical interface which allows you to create an ISO with all of the packages you've downloaded via APT-GET or APTITUDE, creating a removable repository that you can use on other computers.  APTonCD will also allow you to automatically create media with all of your .deb packages located in one specific repository, so that you can install them into your computers without the need for an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also chroot in the environment that will be put on the live db and install the extensions, as explained here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot#Accessing_graphical_applications_inside_the_chroot